# Can we construct a sequence of random variables $(X_i)$ on a metric space with a given distribution such that $d(X_i,X_j)\ge\varepsilon$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, sampling, monte-carlo

Let $E$ be a metric space, $\lambda$ be a measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ (in my application $E=[0,1)^2$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)$ restricted to $E$), $p:E\to[0,\infty)$ with $$c:=\int p\:{\rm d}\lambda\in(0,\infty)$$ and $\varepsilon>0$.

Are we able to sample a sequence $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ of random variables such that $$d(X_m,X_n)\ge\varepsilon\;\;\;\text{for all }m,n\in\{1,\ldots,N\}\tag1$$ and $$X_i\sim\frac pc\lambda\tag2\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$$ or at least the distribution of $X_n$ converges (in a suitable sense) to $\frac pc\lambda$?

An obvious approach would be to sample $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ independent and identically distributed and discard all samples which do not satisfy the constraint $(1)$. However, is the resulting process still distributed according to $(2)$? ([This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4586508/47771) is related.)

*EDIT*: As far as I can tell from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/558502/222528), it should at least be possible to sample from some distributions (in the question it is a normal distribution) with constraints. So, the generation I'm asking for might be possible as well ...

*EDIT 2*: $N$ does not need to be arbitrary here. I would to find the largest $N$ possible satisfying $(1)$ and either $(2)$ or $(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly not possible for arbitrary $N$, as when $N$ is large enough, there is  no such configuration at all.
The choice of $p$ will also affect the the maximum possible $N$, as the more peaked the distribution, the fewer points will "fit."
For instance, taking $p(x) = \mathbf{1}_{0 \leq x < \epsilon}$ will only allow $N = 4$.

In the special case of the uniform distribution $p \equiv 1$, you can drop a hexagonal lattice with edge length $\epsilon$ uniformly at random over $[0, 1)^2$ (this can be done by sampling a base point uniformly at random from $[0, 1)^2$ and then choosing an edge direction uniformly at random, and this will determine the whole lattice).

Now, $X_n$ can be chosen by sampling vertices from the lattice without replacement.

Comment: How do you prove that in your example onyl $N=4$ is allowed? Do you need to assume that the $(X_n)$ are indepenendet (which I did not assume) to show this?

Comment: $N$ doesn't need to be arbitrary. I would like to find the largest $N$ possible.