# If $(X_n)$ is iid and $I=\inf\{n\ge 2:d(X_1,X_n)\ge\varepsilon\}$, what is the distribution of $X_I$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, sampling-theory

Let

- $(E,d)$ be a metric space
- $\lambda$ be a measure on $\mathcal B(E)$
- $p:E\to[0,\infty)$ with $$c:=\int p\:{\rm d}\lambda\in(0,\infty)$$ and $$\mu:=\frac{p\lambda}c$$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an $E$-valued independent identically $\mu$-distributed process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $(x_0,\varepsilon)\in E\times(0,\infty)$ and $$I:=\left\{n\in\mathbb N:d(x_0,X_n)\ge\varepsilon\right\}$$

> How can we determine the distribution of $X_I$? Does the distribution admit a density with respect to $\lambda$? If so, what is this density?

Let $$A:=\left\{x\in E:d(x_0,x)<\varepsilon\right\}.$$ Assume $$\mu(A)<1.$$ We should have $$\operatorname P\left[I=n,X_n\in B\right]=\mu(A)^{n-1}\mu(A^c\cap B)\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N$$ and hence $$\operatorname P\left[X_I\in B\right]=\frac{\mu(A^c\cap B)}{1-\mu(A)}\tag2$$ for all $B\in\mathcal B(E)$.

But how can we determine the density of the distribution? (I would like to evaluate this density in a computer program and hence need a suitable expression for it.)

Comment: You could simulate it.

Comment: @Mason What do you mean?

Comment: Assume $c = 1$, so that $p$ is a probability density. You could use a computer program to sample from $X_I$ and estimate the density of $X_I$. But now looking at it, it might be good to condition on $X_1$. Then given $X_1 = x$, we have $X_I$ has the same distribution as what you get when choosing the first $X_j$ for which $d(X_j, x) \geq \varepsilon$. This should have density $p_{X_I}(y \mid X_1 = x) = \frac{1}{P(d(X_1, x) \geq \varepsilon)}p(y)I(|y - x| \geq \varepsilon)$. Then integrate this against $p(x)$ to get the marginal density $p_{X_I}(y)$.

Comment: @Mason Please take note of my edit.

Comment: My answer is $p_{X_I}(y) = \int_{E}\frac{p(y)}{P(d(X_1, x) \geq \varepsilon)}I(|y - x| \geq \varepsilon)p(x)\,\lambda(dx)$.

Comment: @Mason You are right, the density is $\frac1{c(1-\mu(A))}1_{A^c}p$.